# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Dell Precision 3540 Boot weirdness

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

Having some very strange issues.

New windows 10 laptop and have shrunk the Windows partition down to make room for Ubuntu.

Installed Ubuntu into said space with the custom option and set up my / swap and /home partitions. Install seemed to go fine have updated etc.

Reboot and get the grub boot choice menu. If i let it time out on the default option of Ubuntu it boots fine 90% of the time. if i hit return to make it boot before time out about 90% of the time i get a black screen and no more.

Haven't got a clue whats happening as there is no error on screen

Id like to make Windows the default OS in grub as well but a little bit apprehensive of changing the grub default if it ends up making the ubuntu install inaccessible if it wont boot properly without it timing out.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why a manual selection of the default would not boot when auto time out seems to work fine? Is there any log i can read from here to try and decipher this?

Appreciate any advice anyone can offer, im by no means a guru but know my way around the command line reasonably well and operate a couple of Pi servers at home. 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please ask one question at a time. See [the site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for guidance on how to ask questions in this site. I have no clue about your sporadic black screen on boot problem. Search the site for already answered questions if you need help on changing the default GRUB option.

Answer (score 1):

Grub only boots working Windows. So if Windows turns fast start up back on with an update which it often does, or needs chkdsk grub will not boot it. But if UEFI install, you should be able to directly boot from UEFI boot menu and may be able to make repairs or change settings. Best to always have Windows repair flash drive and Ubuntu live installer for current versions of systems installed.

You can change default in grub menu. Some just change number, but description is easier to know which is which. I once changed to a blank line which did not work very well.

You need exact description in grub of your Windows entry. Example will not be yours. Best to always back up grub & grub configuration files.

```
sudo cp -a /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg.backup
sudo cp -a /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
```

List grub entries, you want exact Windows entry. Copy from listing into grub.

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg  | grep menuentry

sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=0

change to comment # or delete old and add new :
#GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)"
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Specific_Entries

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately fast boot didnt seem to affect how often Ubuntu actually boots successfully. Im now going to do a clean remove of ubuntu and grub, repair windows boot loader and start again with 18.04 in case this is some kind if incompatibility

Comment: This answer was only on the question about making Windows first.